# Python: Replace duplicate values in a list with the same values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, duplicates

I have a list and would like to convert all duplicates values to 3 without changing the order and without importing any packages

```
X = [1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6]
```

Desired output:

```
X = [1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 8, 6]
```

Comment: Create a set from `X` `Y = set(X)`, then iterate through `X` and check if the value is contained in `Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why another user deleted their answer but that was a pretty simple one and uses basic list comprehension. So I am bringing the same to you. Please refer the code below for same:

```
X = [1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6]
print([3 if e==2 else e for e in X])
```

Comment: I think they removed this answer because it only works for this case or only in cases where 2 is a duplicate value because it replaces the value 2 with the value 3.
But if we want to replace duplicate values ​​that are not 2, unfortunately that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Among the fastest**

```
fr = {x:0 for x in X}
for n in X:
    fr[n] += 1
Y = [3 if fr[n]>1 else n for n in X]
```

You iterate over the list and add one to the dictionary counter for that number.
Then you create a list with list comprehension: you change the value to 3 if it is repeated more than once.

**Little bit slower and little bit shorter**

```
xi = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(X)}
dp = {x: xi[x]>i for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(X)))}
Y = [3 if dp[x] else x for x in X]
```

You iterate over X and keep the lastest index of each value. Then you iterate again but in reverse order, and ask if there is another index for that value. Then with that info you create the desired output. All using list/dict comprehension. This is more of a functional approach.

Answer (score 1):

This code automatically replace all duplicate items with 3

```
my_list = [1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6]
new = []
for item in my_list:
   if my_list.count(item) > 1:
    new.append(3)
   else:
    new.append(item)
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a for loop for this

```
my_list = [1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6]
new_list = []

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] in new_list:
        new_list.append(3)
    else:
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
 [1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 8, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
X = [t if t not in X[:i] + X[i+1:] else 3 for i, t in enumerate(X)]
```